# Network configuration (wifi and ethernet) with yocto

Tags: networking, yocto, systemd

I have an embedded system based on yocto with systemd.
There is 2 interfaces eth0 and wlan0, both configured using DHCP (ipv4) delivered by my router (internet box).

```
/etc/systemd/network/20-wired.network

[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=10
```

```
/etc/systemd/network/25-wireless.network

[Match]
Name=wlan0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=20
```

Here is the output of *ip route*:

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  src 192.168.1.47  metric 10 
default via 192.168.1.1 dev wlan0  src 192.168.1.88  metric 20 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.1.47 
192.168.1.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link  src 192.168.1.88 
192.168.1.1 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.1.47  metric 10 
192.168.1.1 dev wlan0 scope link  src 192.168.1.88  metric 20
```

So ping to another device on the network (192.168.1.42) is working from eth0 but not wlan0, except when I disable eth0.

```
192.168.1.47  =>  192.168.1.42 : OK (eth0)
192.168.1.88  =>  192.168.1.42 : KO (wlan0)
192.168.1.42  =>  192.168.1.47 : OK (eth0)
192.168.1.42  =>  192.168.1.88 : OK (wlan0)
```

Here is the output of */etc/resolv.conf* (handled by systemd-resoved):

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver fe80::a63e:51ff:fe70:9e16%3
nameserver 2a01:cb08:9049:3200:a63e:51ff:fe70:9e16
```

How can I do to have both interfaces (eth0 and wlan0) working at the same time without disabling on or the other ?

Regards

Comment: just curious, ... did you try to put ETH0 and WLAN0 into different subnets?